# Consider the sequence of real numbers defined by the relations: $X(1)=1$ and $X(n+1)=\sqrt{1+2X(n)}$ for $n\geq1$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

How can I use the principle of mathematical induction to show that $X(n)<4$ for all $n\geq1$ where $X(n)$ is defined as $$X(n)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1+2X(n-1)}&n\neq1\\1&n=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Did you mean $X_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+2X_n}$?

Comment: $\sqrt {1+(2)(4)} =\sqrt 9 =3 <4$.

Comment: Yes I meant this Xn+1=√1+2Xn..a typing error .so how do I do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and bounded from above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987861/show-that-a-n-is-an-increasing-sequence-and-bounded-from-above)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It suffices to note that the range of the function $f: [1,4) \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + 2x}$ is $[1,3)$.

More specifically: we are showing that $1 \leq X(n) < 4$ for all integers $n\geq 1$, using the fact that $X(n+1) = f(X(n))$ for all $n \geq 1$.  The base case is that this holds for $n = 1$.  The inductive step is to show that if this holds for $n = k$, then it also holds for $n = k+1$.

Comment: Okay but how does the proof work using mathematical induction

Comment: See my latest edit